# How to send an array from an HTML page to Node.js and then store it on a database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, mysql-workbench

I need help transferring an array made in javascript. I'm confused on how to use node.js and then send it to MySql. Any links to useful videos or an explanation would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read up on using ajax

Comment: I have the code, but I've never worked with node.js. Most videos that I found on google used different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading up on this a bit with [useful tutorials](https://dev.to/achowba/build-a-simple-app-using-node-js-and-mysql-19me).

That said, the basic way to do this is to use an NPM package like [MYSQL2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2). You then loop through your array to create an insert statement:

```js
// get the client
const mysql = require('mysql2');
 
// create the connection to database
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  database: 'test'
});

/*
Assuming your database has a table named `employee` with a two columns: id and name.

Goal: INSERT INTO employee(id,name)
VALUES 
   (1,"Jerry"),
   (2,"Jenny"),
   (3,"Jessie"); */
   
var ary=[{id: 1, name: "Jerry"}, {id: 2, name:"Jenny"}, {id: 3, name: "Jessie"}];
var values = ary.map(a => {
  return `(${a.id}, ${a.name})`;
});

// simple query
connection.query(
  'INSERT INTO employee(id, name) VALUES ' + values.join(','),
  function(err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results); // results contains rows returned by server
    console.log(fields); // fields contains extra meta data about results, if available
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have an idea of how it works now. I will read the tutorials attached on your answer.